# Opencart 1.5.6 "Use Reward Point" Option Not showing

Tags: opencart

I used Opencart version 1.5.6. **I did allocate reward points to product and customer.** But  "Use Reward Point" option not showing. **After I went to "Extention->Order Total" and enable reward point option again.** But still not showing option "Use Reward Point".

Could any one help me to find the error. I installed open cart in local pc.

Comment: Is this option allowed in administration? In the settings (probably Options tab) You can specify, whether the reward points are allowed at all...

Answer (score 1):

If the customer have the reward points and the Product is also available with reward points.

Simply go to View Cart or Shopping cart page (yourdomain/index.php?route=checkout/cart) where you can see the option weather you want to buy product using reward points, Coupons, gift voucher etc.

[image]